# Add values into Array and find the biggest one in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out this small question: user inputs as many marks as he/she wants, but once mark smaller than 0 or bigger than 100 was entered, program should stop and find out biggest mark form ones that were entered.

I was thinking of getting all marks and adding them to array (Then I found out that using ArrayList is better, so I used it instead).

Here is what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.*;

...
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your mark:");

int mark = input.nextInt();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)
{
    list.add(mark);
}
```

The line `list.add(mark);` gives me error saying something like method adding int was not found.

I'm new to java and I'm not sure if I understood arrayList correctly. Could anyone correct me if I'm wrong? Also once I sort issue with adding values into array, how would I find the biggest number in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REQUIREMENT:** user inputs as many marks as he/she wants, but once mark smaller than 0 or bigger than 100 was entered, program should stop and find out biggest mark form ones that were entered.

Why use an array at all? If you are not required to use an array, then this snippet will do the job ...

```
String instr;
int val, maxval = 0;
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while ((instr = input.readLine())!=null) { 
    val = Integer.parseInt(instr);
    if (val < 0 || val > 100) break;
    maxval = Math.max(maxval, val);
}
input.close();
System.out.println(maxval);
```

Answer (score 2):

`mark` is an `int`, your List saves `String`. you can change it to this

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {
    list.add(mark);
}
```

to make it work.

But then you have an **infinite loop**!! Change `while` to `if` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are declaring an `ArrayList` of String: -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And you are adding an integer to it. Compiler will cry onto that. Declare your `List` as `List<Integer>`.

---

Secondly, you should better maintain the maximum value everytime you enter something into the `List`, to avoid using `search` on the `List` later on.

So, I would modify your code as: -

```
    int maximum = -1;
    int mark = input.nextInt();

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {

        if (maximum < mark) {
            maximum = mark;
        }

        list.add(mark);
    }
```

Now I leave it to you to convert that `if` into a `do-while` loop so as to continue asking marks from user.

Answer (score 1):

For list you define which type of items you have there inside `< >`

change

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do {
       try
       {
         Integer mark = input.nextInt(); //get your input in the loop
         list.add(mark);
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException exception) 
       {
          exception.printStackTrace() ;
       }
    }while (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100);
```

Get your input in the loop, you may want to use a do while loop, so that it runs at least *once*. Also assume the user is malicious and would crash your program.. So prepare for that case by using a `try catch block`. I just used `printStackTrace` but show a nicer error message.

Comment: `List<int>` is not possible, you need `List<Integer>`!

Comment: Mmn, ok I didn't know that. There is learning in answering :)

Answer (score 0):

When you define list, you are defining it as type  and then adding a primitive int to the list. You need to make sure these match.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the corrections you need to do :

1.You are trying to create a list of integers but you are declaring the list of Strings.You need to use Integer(wrapper class for integers) in the declaration.Lists cannot be used with primitive types.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

2.You are taking the input just once and using it in the check condition of the loop due to which loop will run continuously if the input mark satisfies the condition.What you need to do is to place an input statement inside your loop.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your mark:");
    int mark = input.nextInt();
    int max=-1;
    while (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {
        list.add(mark);
         if (max < mark) {
        max = mark;
    }

      System.out.println("Enter your mark:");
         mark = input.nextInt();
    }
```